# Can't find artifact bitcoinj:jar:0.11

Tags: git, maven, bitcoin

Please see the output of the terminal below. I looked online at https://distribution.bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/releases & could only find up to v0.10.3. But according to http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/wiki/UsingMaven v0.11 is the most current?

```
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ bitcoinj-examples >>>
Downloading: https://distribution.bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/releases/com/google/bitcoinj/0.11/bitcoinj-0.11.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/bitcoinj/0.11/bitcoinj-0.11.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.google:bitcoinj:jar:0.11 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://distribution.bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/releases/com/google/bitcoinj/0.11/bitcoinj-0.11.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/bitcoinj/0.11/bitcoinj-0.11.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.278s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 11 13:45:19 EST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bitcoinj-examples: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.google:bitcoinj-examples:jar:0.11: Could not find artifact com.google:bitcoinj:jar:0.11 in bitcoinj-distribution (https://distribution.bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/releases) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I realize the pages were updated within the last 4-5 days but am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show your pom.xml and repositories from settings.xml

Comment: Having a look at the URL `https://distribution.bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/releases/com/google/bitcoinj/` in a browser, it appears that the latest release there is 0.10.3.  Maybe the 0.11 release hasn't yet made it into the repo?

Comment: Thanks @max_yashin I put the info below.

Comment: @msandiford I was thinking the same thing but I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I've made no changes to bitcoinj/examples/pom.xml file since the initial pull. It has both group & artifact ID along with version.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
        com.google
        bitcoinj-parent
        0.11
    
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>bitcoinj-examples</artifactId>

<name>bitcoinj Examples</name>
<description>A collection of examples using the bitcoinj library</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>bitcoinj</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.167</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As far as settings.xml go I don't see it? See the termimal output below, I believe the search command was correct.

```
vbox@vbox-VirtualBox:~/bitcoinj$ find . -type f -name '*.xml'
./tools/pom.xml
./wallettemplate/pom.xml
./pom.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.BloomFilterTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.ECKeyTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.uri.BitcoinURITest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.BlockTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.protocols.payments.PaymentSessionTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.WalletTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.crypto.BIP32Test.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.PeerGroupTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.Base58Test.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.protocols.channels.ChannelConnectionTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.net.discovery.SeedPeersTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.crypto.ChildKeyDerivationTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.AlertMessageTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.BlockChainTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.PeerAddressTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.H2FullPrunedBlockChainTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.LazyParseByteCacheTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.utils.ExponentialBackoffTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.MemoryPoolTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.crypto.MnemonicCodeTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.script.ScriptTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.ChainSplitTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.wallet.DefaultCoinSelectorTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.VarIntTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.store.SPVBlockStoreTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.BitcoinSerializerTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.store.WalletProtobufSerializerTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.AddressTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.MemoryFullPrunedBlockChainTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.UtilsTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.crypto.KeyCrypterScryptTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.PostgresFullPrunedBlockChainTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.protocols.channels.PaymentChannelStateTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.crypto.HDUtilsTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.TransactionBroadcastTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.PeerTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.VersionMessageTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.core.CoinbaseBlockTest.xml
./core/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.google.bitcoin.wallet.DefaultRiskAnalysisTest.xml
./core/pom.xml
./core/findbugs.xml
./examples/pom.xml
vbox@vbox-VirtualBox:~/bitcoinj$
```

Answer (score -1):

https://bitcoinj.github.io/using-maven

I had a similar issue, tried messing the POM files and reading up on Maven. I think I may have installed certain components in the wrong order.  Started from scratch and this worked for me:

1. Installed maven via homebrew (on mac OSX Mavericks)
2. Followed commands in link above using git